# If a twilio callstatus is no-answer, how do I get it to route to another number?

Tags: c#, twilio

```
 if (OkToCall)
        {
            if (CallCount == 0)
            {
                voiceResponse.Say(sayMessage);
                voiceResponse.Dial(number: number1, timeout: 24, action: new Uri("/OnCall/?Location=" + Location + "&CallCount=1", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else if (CallCount == 1)
            {
                sayMessage = "We're sorry. There was no answer. You are now being redirected to the on call manager. One moment. ";
                voiceResponse.Say(sayMessage);
                voiceResponse.Dial(number: number2, timeout: 24, action: new Uri("/OnCall/?Location=" + Location + "&CallCount=2", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else
            {
                sayMessage = "We're sorry. We were unable to connect your call. Please try again later.";
                voiceResponse.Say(sayMessage);
                voiceResponse.Hangup();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sayMessage = "We're sorry. An error occured while redirecting your call. Please try again later.";
            voiceResponse.Say(sayMessage);
            voiceResponse.Hangup();
        }
```

The process above works great, except if the callee hangs up before the caller does, then the caller is routed to the next person. I want to check call status to see if it needs to be routed or not. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The general logic is covered in this Twilio Function.

[Implement voicemail](https://www.twilio.com/docs/wireless/tutorials/communications-guides/implement-voicemail)

```
/**
 *  Voicemail Action URL
 * 
 *  This Function is used in as the action URL in a Dial. If the call isn't answered or the line is busy, 
 *  the call is forwarded to a specified Voicemail URL.
 */

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  // set-up the variables 
  // generate the TwiML to tell Twilio how to forward this call
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  if (event.DialCallStatus === "completed") {
    twiml.hangup();
  }
  else {
    twiml.redirect('<URL-TO-VOICEMAIL-TWIML>');
  }

  // return the TwiML
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```